# Using @media to display an image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Using the @media tag, how do I display a new image, for example I have a logo I want to use for my main site and a mobile logo for my mobile site, how to I display the smaller logo only on the mobile site using @media?

I've tied using "display:url('xxxx') but that hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: `display: url('xxx')` is not a thing in CSS. There is a such thing as `background: url('xxxx')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to put two logos on your HTML, like this:

```
<img src="" class="desktop-logo">
<img src="" class="mobile-logo">
```

Then, you'll have to hide the mobile-logo by default:

```
.mobile-logo {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, on your media query, you'll have to hide the desktop-logo and show the mobile-logo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .desktop-logo {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile-logo {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this much more than setting a background image on a div

Comment: Setting a background didn't work, but this has worked a treat! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: To explain my downvote. This technique will force the browser to download both images. The background image technique would only result in one download.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is create an element and set a background on it. You'll use @media control what the background image is based on the size of the window.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .logo {
    background: url('image.jpg');
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .logo {
    background: url('imagesmall.jpg');
  }
}
```

And this is what your element would look like.

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create a tag with a class then use mediascreen to apply new styles to said class

create a div tag

css/

```
@media screen .... etc {
    .image {background-image: url('wwww....');
}
```

So, when the exact pixels are reached at the screen it will apply a backround image to that image class I created above.